# How to increment a value in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, resolve

I had tried to increment the variable loopVal inside the promise but I am unable to increment it. How can I do that?

```js
const hi = function(delay) {
  let loopVal = 1;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Resolved Successfully", loopVal);
      resolve();
      loopVal++;
    }, delay)
  })
}

const bye = async() => {
  await hi(1000);
  await hi(1000);
  return "bye";
}

bye().then((value) => console.log(value));
```

Comment: Where in your code is the increment?

Comment: @Bergi any idea to increment the loopVal

Comment: You print the value before incrementing the value. Not async related at all

Comment: each `hi` method has its own `loopVal` so the two separate calls will never increment the same variable.

Comment: @JAVIDASHWAQF Thanks for the edit, but why are your incrementing *after* you log it? What is the expected output?

Comment: Also, it's called `loopVal`, but there is not loop?

Comment: loopVal is set to 1 every time you call the function. It does not maintain state.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `loopVal` is local to the function, its changes are discarded as soon as the function terminates.

Second, you don't return the changed value from the promise.

One of possible approaches is to have this variable in a scope where it can be both used as an argument and a return value from your `hi` function

```js
const hi = function(val, delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Resolved Successfully", val);
      resolve(val+1);
    }, delay)
  })
}

const bye = async() => {
  var val = 1;
  val = await hi(val, 1000);
  val = await hi(val, 1000);
  console.log("Final value", val);
  return "bye";
}

bye().then((value) => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are setting loopVal to one every time you call the function. There is no state between each of the function calls. You can do it by using a closure that returns a function so you can maintain the variable's state without having to make a global variable.

```js
const hi = (function() {

  let loopVal = 1;
  
  return function(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Resolved Successfully", loopVal);
        resolve();
        loopVal++;
      }, delay)
    })
  }
}());

const bye = async() => {
  await hi(1000);
  await hi(1000);
  return "bye";
}

bye().then((value) => console.log(value));
```